# How to create a multiple choice inquirer?

Tags: python, inquirer

I am creating a program (using Python) that allows users to automatically generate a TXT file with sentences randomly selected from three files (one for each level: A, B, C). The user can select one or more of these three files and the total number of sentences he needs. I tried to use inquirer:

Select the level:

- A
- B
- C

However, it allows to select only one of the options. Is there a way to select both A and B for example?

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?  what is your code?  do you just want a checkbox?

Comment: You could use a loop to select multiple singular options

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I found it when googling, so here's the answer:

```
inquirer.Checkbox('multiples',
  message="Which modules do you need? (Press <space> to select, Enter when finished).",
  choices=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
```

HTH someone else in the same situation.

Documentation: https://python-inquirer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html